# Sticky '_calc' is not an available method for this element

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, sticky, zurb-foundation-6

I'm trying to invoke the recalculation of the sticky header when using Foundation 6. However everything i attempt returns

> We're sorry, '_calc' is not an available method for this element

Here's the declaration of the sticky element:

```
<div id="sticky-container" data-sticky-container>
    <div id="sticky" data-sticky data-margin-top="0" data-top-anchor="the-table" 
                     data-btm-anchor="footer:bottom" style="width: 100%">
```

I've tried:

```
$('.sticky:visible').foundation('_calc', true);
$('#sticky-container').foundation('_calc', true);
$('#sticky').foundation('_calc', true);
```

All 3 of these usages returns the `_calc` is not available.

Comment: When/where are you using `_calc`?

Comment: @Yass After the page is fully rendered, additionally in the console window of dev tools. Foundation.js and jQuery.js are all available and working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're not calling `$(document).foundation();` directly before the call to `.foundation` with `_calc`. In my tests, I've been able to replicate the error if I call `$('#sticky').foundation('_calc', true);` before `$(document).foundation();` is called. The issue stems from the fact that the sticky element hasn't been initialized when you're calling `$('#sticky').foundation('_calc', true);`

1. [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/q1e45fzz/) where `$(document).foundation();` is called before.
2. **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/Le1j994v/)** where `$(document).foundation();` is called after.

I'm pretty sure the above is the cause. If not, please let me know.

Comment: It was a javascript sequencing issue. I moved the `$(document).foundation()` call to invoke immediately after the `src=foundation.js` instead of allowing any other javascript to run between.

Comment: Cool :) Glad to hear you fixed your issue.